# Prime counting function in the family of sets $N_a=\{n\in N:n=ak+1;\;a,k\in N\}$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Given the family of sets
$$N_a=\{n\in N:n\equiv 1\mod a;\;a\in N\},$$
consider the group $(N_a\,;\,\cdot\,)$ under the ordinary multiplication.

As an example,
$$N_4=\{1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29,...\}$$
In $N_4$ also the numbers $9$ and $21$ are primes, but not $25$.

One could define a prime counting function $\rho_a(x)$ working over the set $N_a$. Then, for example, $\rho_4(30)=6$. Obviously, $\rho_1(x)=\pi(x)\sim\frac{x}{\log x}$.

Is it possible to give an estimate of $\rho_a(x)$?

Comment: Your notation isn't clear.  Does $N_{a,b}$ depend on $k$?  And since when is $N_{a,b}$  a group under multiplication?

Comment: I made a mistake ... now I have limited the definition to the case $b=1$.

Comment: Both of my objections are still valid.  If your set depends on the choice of $k$, why leave it off of the notation?  And your set is obviously not a group under multiplication.

Comment: In any case, Dirichlet's theorem also provides the density of primes in a given arithmetic progression.  I expect you can get whatever you want out of that.

Comment: $N_{ab}$ with respect to ordinary multiplication is of course not a group.

Comment: All the composite integers with one prime factor congruent to $1 \bmod 4$ and and an even number (counted with multiplicity) of prime factors congruent to $ 3 \bmod 4$, can't be split in $N_4$.